# Error when trying precompile assets, getting yarn error with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

`rails -v: Rails 6.1.0`

`ruby -v: ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]`

I'm having this error when I try to run `rails assets:precompile`

```
rails aborted!
Errno::ENOEXEC: Exec format error - C:/Users/trynot/Desktop/prolife/bin/yarn --version

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => yarn:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What I've tried:

I already uninstalled and reinstalled all my gems, tried to update all my gems, tried to generate a new project with the flags `--skip-webpack-install`, tried removing the file `yarn` from `bin`, and tried to reinstall yarn. Same problem!

Comment: The trace is complaining about this `rails aborted!
Errno::ENOEXEC: Exec format error - "C:/hamdevco/beneke_tools/bin/yarn" --version
C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/tasks/yarn.rake:13:in ``'`

Comment: That comes from this block `yarn_flags =
      if `"#{Rails.root}/bin/yarn" --version`.start_with?("1")
        "--no-progress --frozen-lockfile"
      else
        "--immutable"
      end`

Comment: So rails is not getting a response when windows runs `"#{Rails.root}/bin/yarn" --version`

Comment: if the line instead read `ruby "#{Rails.root}/bin/yarn" --version` it should work universally.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved on this commit `https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5c8805034f5f59b7278f895fca7b6fd7dfda7af5#diff-7c64b5585b553fe2873f6b3cee2675a6d63997f3c7af82ccf23c1073773c40d3`